# Delete file in directory with extension

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtcore, qfile

Hi I'm trying to iterate through directories and remove files with the extension "~" here is my code

```
    QString path = "/home/brett/sweetback";
    QDirIterator it(path, QDirIterator::Subdirectories);
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        //ui.textEdit->append(QString(it.next()));
        QFileInfo Info(it.next());
        //ui.textEdit->append(QString(Info.fileName()));
        QString testName = QString(Info.fileName());
        QString subString = testName.right(1);
        if(subString == QString("~")){  
                //wnat to remove file here

            ui.textEdit->append(QString(subString));
            remove(QString( testName));
        }
   }
```

I can list the file fine but cant figure out how to delete them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [QFile::remove()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfile.html#remove-2)

It's a static member of QFile, so you would use it like this:

```
QFile::remove(testName);
```

Answer (score 2):

[bool QFile::remove(const QString & fileName) [static]](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfile.html#remove-2)

> This is an overloaded function.
>
> Removes the file specified by the fileName given.
>
> Returns true if successful; otherwise returns false.

So, change your code:

```
remove(QString( testName));
```

to:

```
if (!QFile::remove(testName))
    qDebug() << "Could not remove the file:" << testName;
```

Note that you do not need to cast a `QString` to `QString` explicitly. That is superfluous.

You could also use the [non-static member method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfile.html#remove), and then you could even get the error string by using `errorString()` for the `QFile` instance when the deletion is not successful.

If you would also like to delete whole directories recursively having the desired `~` suffix, you would need to use the [remove member method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qdir.html#remove) in `QDir` for such cases.